# How to add long-form subcommand documentation in a clap CLI?

Tags: rust, clap

I'm using `#[derive(Subcommand)]` to introduce subcommands in my CLI:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    /// Create a new config file
    ///
    /// Line one
    ///    Line two
    Init,
}
```

However, the documentation in long form help mode ends up being distorted. More precisely, when running `mycli init --help`, I get the following documentation output:

```
Create a new config file

Line one

Line two
```

Is there a way to add delicately formatted subcommand documentation (in the same way `long_about=` works for the CLI overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `#[verbatim_doc_comment]`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    /// Create a new config file
    ///
    /// Line one
    ///    Line two
    #[command(verbatim_doc_comment)]
    Init,
}
```

Output:

```
Create a new config file

Line one
   Line two

Usage: cli init

Options:
  -h, --help
          Print help information (use `-h` for a summary)
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=13f6c3b6c21350f4b6ad9dc34124d003)